# Mapping of registers to gate level Verilog

Tags: yosys

I am using Yosys to synthesize an AES core to gate level Verilog with mapping to cells from a Liberty file.

Is there a way to report the mapping of registers and memory instances from the RTL to the gate level instances/pins/nets?

This is my version:

```
Yosys 0.8+     510 (git sha1 1217e47e, clang 10.0.1 -fPIC -Os)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see more names preserved using `write_verilog -norename`. In some cases, Yosys will also add a `(* src = "..." *)` attribute tracking the original source location.